# How to set a variable with modifying behavior to another variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, output

A few of the related questions come close but don't directly answer my issue.  I'm trying to set a variable that has an attached sed command to a new variable. What I've tried:

```
NEW_VARIABLE="$OUTPUT | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1"    
NEW_VARIABLE=($OUTPUT | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
NEW_VARIABLE=$(OUTPUT | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
NEW_VARIABLE=(${OUTPUT} | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
NEW_VARIABLE=`$OUTPUT | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

Given that $OUTPUT spits out a number with a # sign. (e.g. #89) The sed cuts off the # and just spits out 89.  I'd like to set that output to a new variable. Am I close?

Comment: we'll need to sample input, and expected output to be of help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pipe a variable to a command, you need to use `echo` or `printf`.

```
NEW_VARIABLE=$(printf '%s\n' "$OUTPUT" | sed -e 's/.*\#//' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

When you just put it in the command alone, the shell will try to execute its contents as a command, not print it.

You can also use a here-string:

```
NEW_VARIABLE=$(sed -e 's/.*\#//' <<<"$OUTPUT" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

But even better is to just use the shell's built-in expansion operators:

```
# Remove everything until last #
NEW_VARIABLE=${OUTPUT##*#}
# Remove everything after first space
NEW_VARIABLE=${NEW_VARIABLE% *}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about the built-in operators.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed` or `cut` for this. Use `read` and parameter expansion operators.

```
read NEW_VARIABLE rest <<< "${OUTPUT##*#}"
```

`

Comment: Thanks for this as well